# Schedule jobs with Node-schedule

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, scheduled-tasks

I'm using a node module called [node-schedule](https://github.com/mattpat/node-schedule)

I have this function, it is expected to fire ONCE at the start of each quarter.

```
var rule = {hour: 0, minute: 0, day: 1, month: [0, 3, 6, 9]};

var logCost = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function(){
  console.log('logCost output this shit at: ' + dateFormat(Date(), 'isoTime'));
});
```

The problem is that the function just keeps executing during the whole day (the first day of the month that is). How do I re-write this to execute just ONCE, there is probably something wrong with my rule variable, but i dont see what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give a try with this:

```
var rule = {hour: 00, minute: 01, dayOfWeek: 01, month: [0, 3, 6, 9]};
var logCost = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function(){
          console.log('logCost output this shit at: ' + dateFormat(Date(), 'isoTime'));
});
```

Check here: 
https://github.com/mattpat/node-schedule

It should be "dayOfWeek", and not "day".

Answer (score 1):

You can also try with this code:

```
var logCost = schedule.scheduleJob('1 0 * * *', function(){
  console.log('logCost output this shit at: ' + new Date());
});
```

The above code will be executed daily at 00:01 (12:01 AM).